# Change values in column if the correct ones are present in list (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of 'right' sizes.

```
list_sizes=['YT trueview', 'YT TRUEVIEW something', 'YT pre-roll', 'YT bumper', 'YT preferred pre-roll', 'YT preferred bumper', 'YT masthead','Advertorials', 'Editorial Content']
```

And a column of a df with the same sizes that, sometimes, are written in the wrong upper/lower cases.

```
Size
______

YT TRUEVIEW
YT PRE-ROLL
YT TRUEVIEW something
```

I want to check in the list if the lower/upper cases are correct. If not, I want to substitute with the right one. The match must be exact (not considering the upper/lower cases). My expected output is:

```
Size
______

YT trueview
YT pre-roll
YT TRUEVIEW something
```

How can i do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a mapping dictionary which maps the lower case strings to their corresponding representation in `list_size`, then use **[`.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html)** + **[`.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)** on column `Size` to substitute the matching representation from mapping `dict`:

```
dct = dict(zip(map(str.lower, list_sizes), list_sizes))
df['Size'] = df['Size'].str.lower().replace(dct)
```

---

```
                    Size
0            YT trueview
1            YT pre-roll
2  YT TRUEVIEW something
```